# Treeview для android

Tags: android, kotlin, treeview, expandablelistview

Только начал изучать Android, столкнулся с проблемой реализации TreeView. В WPF и WinForm есть реализация из коробки, но вот в Android такого не нашел. Нашел реализации различные сторонними библиотеками, но им всем по 3-5 лет. Искал реализации на Kotlin, но там все еще печальнее.
Есть идея сделать ExpandableListView, а в дочерний элемент узла вставить еще один ExpandableListView, но все это очень похоже на костыль.

Comment: В Андроиде tree-view считается не каноном. Рассмотрите лучше другие способы добиться схожего эффекта.

Comment: Буду очень признателен если подскажите чем можно заменить!

Comment: Тут всё от конкретной задачи зависит. Можно на следующий экран проваливаться, можно другое что-то придумать. Например, как навигация в стандартном приложении Files